# How to get Profile ID in paypal via API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm doing some paypal integration in my application and bumped in on cancelling a RecurringPayments. To cancel a Recurring Payment, I need a Profile ID, I do not know where to get the Profile ID, can someone guide me here.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm using this code: https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example/downloads, I hope you can answer my question now.

Comment: Is PayerID and ProfileID the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use PayPal API's 'GetTransactionDetails' method to get the details related to a particular transaction.

You have to pass the TransactionID as the parameter along with your request.
And it will respond back with all the details(which includes the SubscriptionID/ProfileID as well) related to that transaction.

Follow this link: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetTransactionDetails

Hope it helps you.

Thank you.

Comment: @julianm, this answer is from 2012, at that time, NVP API was the main API.. now they're treated as "legacy"

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the Profile-ID without making an API call. You can find it in your PayPal account.

Login to your PayPal account. Go to 'My Account' tab -> Overview
There you will find the list of transactions in 'My recent activity' section.

Identify the Recurring-Payments (Recurring Payments can be identified from their type)
Click on 'Details' for any Recurring transaction. You will be directed to a different page(Transaction Details). Check out the URL of this page. You can get the Profile-ID from there.
OR
Click on 'View details' when you are in the 'Transaction Details' page
You can find the Profile-ID over there

Thank you.

Regards,
Anish

Comment: He asked where to get the Profile Id via the API, not the dashboard. This comment is useless.

Comment: @JellyFishBoy did you upvote the answer above? That was useful

Comment: I downvoted your answer due to it not being useful for the related question. OP asked about the API, not the PayPal dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I will be talking about Paypal API for Express Checkout here, and not Direct Payment.

When you charge subscription payment from customer you need to use Paypal API on 2 counts.

1. First use SetExpressCheckout and get the token sent by paypal.
2. Then use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and get the authorization from the user for starting of the subscription. Along with this request you will also be sending the Token you got, Profile Start Date, Billing Period and Frequency. Once the user confirm, he is sent back to the site with a response array from paypal.

I am sure you have followed the above steps.

In that response, you will see Profile Id of the user. You have to save it somewhere such as database table corresponding to the user in concern.

Finally, when cancelling the subscription you have to pass the profile id and call ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus.

Follow this nice tutorial: http://thereforei.am/2012/07/03/cancelling-subscriptions-created-with-paypal-standard-via-the-express-checkout-api/